# Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ be with $|z|<1$. Then the set $\{\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}} \mid |w|=1, w\in \mathbb{C}\}$ is which of the following curves?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a given complex number with modulus $|z|<1$. Then the set $\{\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}}\mid |w|=1, w\in \mathbb{C}\}$ is a

(A) Straight line.

(B) Hyperbola.

(C) Circle.

(D) Parabola.

I tried to convert this form to some of the standards forms of the curves by applying the properties of complex numbers..after trying everything I did put z=x+iy but it was of no use..please help

Comment: It will be better if you write your thoughts, so that people can understand that you have tried at least.

Comment: You're looking to find the image of the unit circle $|w|=1$ under the Mobius transformation $T_{z_0}(w)=\frac{w-z_0}{z_{0}w-1}$ where $|z_0|<1$ is a fixed element of $\mathbb{C}$. Have you studied Mobius transformations? If you take $z_0$ to be the origin, do you know what you would get?

Comment: No I don't know about this transformation..thank you for telling I will search about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a circle centered in the origin and radius 1, in fact
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar w}\right|^2
&=\frac{z-w}{1-z\bar w}\frac{\bar z-\bar w}{1-\bar z w}\\
&=\frac{|z|^2+1-2\Re(z\bar w)}{1+|z|^2-2\Re(z\bar w)}=1.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

$$ |w| = 1 \rightarrow w \bar{w} = 1$$
$$ \alpha  = \frac{z-w}{1-z\bar{w}} = \frac{z-w}{1-\frac{z}{w}} = (-w)$$
$$ |\alpha| = 1 \; ,hence  \, the  \, set \, represents \, a \, circle$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a *Möbius transformation* here.  Generalized circles are invariant.  That immediately narrows the possibilities down to a circle or a straight line.

But it's a circle, because $1\mapsto-1,-1\mapsto1$ and $i\mapsto -i$.

So this particular transformation maps the disk conformally onto itself and takes $z$ to $0$.